# Linq: Getting missing records

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

So heres my case i got 2 tables one with Languages one with Resources and what i want to do is to find all Resources that is missing on each language...

The default language i wanna go after is languageId = 1

**Table "Resources"**

```
Id    Key    Value    LanguageId
1     k1     test     1
2     k1     test     2
3     k1     test     3
```

**Table "Languages"**

```
Id   
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

language contains about 10 rows of languages.

Now what i wanna do is to take out those resources that dosent exists 
**(ex results)**

```
Key   Value   LanguageId
k1    test    1
k1    test    2
k1    test    3
k1    null    4
k1    null    5
k1    null    6
k1    null    7
```

Any suggestions how to solve this problem, ive tried with GroupJoin And SelectMany but no good results.

Comment: You have 2 DataTable like above or just in database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It feels to me like actually your structure isn't quite right yet: you should have a third table of ResourceKeys, with `k1` in. That way when you add a resource key, the first thing you add is an entry in ResourceKeys, at which point *all* languages will be missing that translation. Otherwise you have no way of representing "a resource with no translations" which is a meaningful concept IMO.

You can then *cross-join* Language and ResourceKeys, and *group join* against Resources:

```
var query = from language in Languages
            from resourceKey in ResourceKeys
            join resource in Resources
                 on new { LangId = language.Id, ResId = resourceKey.Id }
                 equals new { LangId = resource.LanguageId,
                              ResId = resource.Key }
                 into values
            select new { LangId = language.Id,
                         ResId = resourceKey.Id,
                         Value = values.SingleOrDefault() };
```

Comment: Yes, i take out the resource keys to a seperate table with the languageid 1, since that is the key that occurs the most or is the default key that always should exist. just printed out the problem seems like your linq will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
from lang in context.Languages
where !context.Resources.Contains(r => r.LanguageId == lang.LanguageId)
select lang
```